# MCU Input capture

Tags: stm32, pulse

I will do input capture with any mcu. I assume a pulse signal will come as shown in the figure. There is minor noise(A,B,C,D) on the signal. Do these noises cause errors in rising or falling edge capture?
Is there a way to ignore these noises if they are generating errors?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the amplitude of the ringing doesn't come close to the threshold voltages from low to high or vice versa on the MCU input, they will not generate any false triggering of the input capture.

If the amplitude does get that high, you should try removing the ringing in the first place. Depending on speed requirements and the source of the signals, there are some different methods that can be used for that.